# Why is my TableView not showing any content?

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview

I created a simple TableView that gets a countrylist from Firestore.
The network request works fine and I don`t suspect any issue with that.
All variables filled.
No errors showing up in the console.
But my TableView stays empty and not showing up in the UI.

Can somebody see any obvious mistakes in the code below?

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
  [@IBOutlets...]

    var countryList: [Country] = []
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        countriesTableView.delegate = self
        countriesTableView.dataSource = self
        countriesTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CountriesCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountriesCell")
        
        getCountries()
        
    }

    func getCountries (){
        
        NetworkManager.shared.getCountryList { success in
            if success {
                self.countryList = NetworkManager.shared.data!
                self.countriesTableView.reloadData()
                print (self.countryList)
                
            }
            else {
                print ("Error fetching countries")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        populationLabel.text = countryList[indexPath.row].population
        sizeLabel.text = countryList[indexPath.row].size
        countryLabelMain.text = countryList[indexPath.row].name
        
    }
    
    
    
}


extension MainViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        print (countryList.count)
        return countryList.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = countriesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountriesCell", for: indexPath) as! CountriesCell
        
        cell.countryLabel.text = countryList[indexPath.row].name
           
        return cell
    }
      
}
```

Comment: Is `numberOfRowsInSection` called? Same for `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: Yes, i tested them with print functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    countriesTableView.delegate = self
    countriesTableView.dataSource = self

    countriesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60 // use as you need
    countriesTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

    countriesTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CountriesCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountriesCell")
    
    getCountries()
}


func getCountries() {
    
    NetworkManager.shared.getCountryList { success in
        if success {
            self.countryList = NetworkManager.shared.data!

            DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in 
                self?.countriesTableView.reloadData() 
            }
        }
        else {
            print ("Error fetching countries")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not reloading the tableview on the main thread.

Instead of:  `self.countriesTableView.reloadData()`

Try: `DispatchQueue.main.async{[weak self] in self?.countriesTableView.reloadData() }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with cell, set a default value for cell size, or use the default cell

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
             return 70
    }
```